# Use .equals method in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I am checking arraylength.Equals("4") condition inside the if statement and arraylength is string type already defined as a global. Now i want to check that condition should be "<=5" at the place of "4", so how do i write the exact statement at the place of .Equals("4").

code section:

```
if (msgarray.GetValue(0).Equals("it") && arraylength.Equals("4") && VMNStatus)
```

Comment: Could you post this section of your code?

Comment: if (msgarray.GetValue(0).Equals("it") && arraylength.Equals("4") && VMNStatus)

Comment: Why is your arraylength globally defined as a string? It should be an integer...

Comment: Sometimes if something painful/hard-to-do, it means you're doing something else wrong. Carefully consider why `arraylength` is a `string`... it's causing pain here and may need to be refactored.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (arraylength.Length <= 5)
{
  //Do something
}
```

Comment: if (arraylength.Length <= 5)

Answer (score 1):

```
if (if msgarray.GetValue(0).Equals("it") && VMNStatus && int.Parse(arraylength.Length) <= 5)
{
    // ...
}
```

You really shouldn't be representing an array's length with a string though.